# Getting list of users being followed by other user with the information if I follow them too

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a social app and now I'd like to introduce a feature which will allow users to follow each other. My MongoDB model looks like this:

```
{
  _id: <- that MongoDB default id
  username: {type: String},
  following: {type: [String]},
  followed_by: {type: [String]}
}
```

So when Bob wants to follow Alice and Kate, I put Alice's and Kate's `_id` in Bob's `following` array and Bob's `_id` in Alice's and Kate's `followed_by` array which gives us this data:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  username: Bob,
  following: {2, 3},
  followed_by: {}
}

{
  _id: 2,
  username: Alice,
  following: {},
  followed_by: {1}
}

{
  _id: 3,
  username: Kate,
  following: {},
  followed_by: {1}
}
```

And there is me, user number 4, displaying Bob's list of the people he follows. Getting their ids, names and all other data is simple, but at the moment I display the list, I want to know more - I want to know if each person from the list is a person I follow as well.

So instead of getting JSON like this:

```
{
  _id: 2,
  username: Alice
}

{
  _id: 3,
  username: Kate
}
```

Given that I follow Kate, I would rather get this JSON:

```
{
  _id: 2,
  username: Alice,
  following: false
}

{
  _id: 3,
  username: Kate
  following: true
}
```

Is it something that is achievable in MongoDB or should I rather ask for two lists - the list of users followed by Bob and the list of users followed by me - and compare their contents element by element?

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918688/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-in-a-mongodb-category

Comment: what's version of MongoDB do you use?

Comment: [Read docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#with-a-query-filter)